# How to plot user interface

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, matplotlib-animation

NOTE: This is what my code looks like, I keep getting errors with the portion in bold, I would like to be able to plot a straight line with the coordinates starting at 1,1  and ending at (1+lineLength), 1, so that I have a horizontal line. I am not too familiar with python so I would really appreciate your input.

```
lineLengthQuestion = input("What size would you like your line? (Numbers Only)")
lineLengthQuestion = int(lineLengthQuestion)
lineLength = [1 + lineLengthQuestion]
print (f'You entered {lineLengthQuestion}')

x = [1,1]
y = [lineLength, 1]
plt.plot(x, y, color = "black", linewidth = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a one-element list containing a number that is 1 more than `lineLengthQuestion`. I think you want a scalar value, so you don't need the brackets.

```
lineLength = 1 + lineLengthQuestion
```